# How would I go from a set of points representing routes to a set of map tiles for online consumption?

Tags: web-mapping, routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web-based user editable routing application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/web-based-user-editable-routing-application)

I have a set of routes as a text file with coordinates.  For each coordinate I also have whether or not it is an intersection with another route.  I'm completely new to GIS and I'd like to know how I can go from these paths to an online map showing the routes.

I'd like to use all free software and would like the resulting tiles to be usable in something like openLayers.  I would also like to perform routing algorithms on the paths later, so I think using a spatial database would be appropriate.  I'm just not sure what steps would be involved and what software should be used.  Also, since I'm completely new, if you can recommend any books, tutorials, or videos that would be great too.  Thanks!

Comment: This question is about generating static tiles not vector layers like the possible duplicate that was flagged, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/web-based-user-editable-routing-application

Comment: The other questions/answers were not what I was looking for either.  The question is about creating map tiles.  The answer I found was TileMill (which uses Mapnik).

Answer (score 0):

this question have been asked before many times. i have replied it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/23600/3071) . you can get same info [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24040/3071) and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/gomogi/campus-indoor-routing-with-open-source)....

and i have been using ArcGIS Network Analysis Services for routing. also you can get information [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/08/17/arcgis-online-geocoding-and-routing-services-updated/) too

i hope it helps you..

Comment: I think my question is different since I don't want to generate the route in open layers.  I want my routes to be plotted on rasterized tiles and then served to a front end like open layers.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a linestring from your calculated route and return that as a (Geo)JSON object from the database via some kind of API. Then all you have to do is to plot this on your tile based web map as an overlay (leaflet for example natively supports GeoJSON).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to combine something into the actual tiles, not draw on top.

Comment: Why don't you want to use vector data in the frontend? It's much easier than setting up a complete tile rendering environment. The only thing I could possibly imagine would be data protection...

Comment: I will have hundreds of routes that need to be displayed simultaneously and the map will need to be viewed on many different devices.  Imagine if you are plotting all of the highways and interstates in the U.S.  I don't think drawing them on the client-side would be the best solution, would it?